# Dealing with database reads in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, side-effects, purely-functional

I am trying to 'purify' some of my Clojure functions.  I would like to get to a point where all my side-effecting code is explicitly declared in one function.  It's easy to get some data at the start and to write it to a db at the end and just have a pure function transforming in between.  However, the usual situation is that the transformation function requires another DB read somewhere in the middle of the logic:

```
(defn transform-users
      [users]
      (let [ids (map :id users)
            profiles (db/read :profiles ids)]
       (profiles->something profiles)))

(->> (db/read :users)
     (transform-users)
     (db/write :something)
```

Obviously this is a very simple example but the point is, how do I get the side-effecting `db/read` function out of there, how can I make `transform-users` pure (and as a benefit, easily testable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do here would be a dependency-injection-like approach of supplying the (potentially) side-effectful function as an optional parameter, e.g.:

```
(defn transform-users
  [users & {:keys [ids->profiles]
            :or {ids->profiles #(db/read :profiles %)}]
  (let [ids (map :id users)
        profiles (ids->profiles ids)]
    (profiles->something profiles)))
```

This should be easily testable since you can mock the injected functions without a lot of effort. And as a bonus, by supplying the default value, you're documenting what you're expecting and making the function convenient to call.

Comment: I think I am going to play with this approach. Using the arrow naming convention can help in documenting things. Looks a little bit Haskell though, I fear one day I will turn to the dark side!  I'm not sure about a default function as I don't want to rely on a namespace such as `db` if I don't need to although it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why couple the reading of the profiles with transforming profiles?

```
  (->> (db/read :users)
       (map :id)
       (db/read :profiles)
       (profile->something)
       (db/write :something)
```

(This also exposes the fact that you are doing two round trips to the db. Where is  `db/read :user-profiles`  ?)

```
  (->> (db/read :user-profiles)
       (profile->something)
       (db/write :something)
```

or perhaps:

```
  (->> (read-profiles-from-users)
       (profile->something)
       (db/write :something)
```

Comment: The point is that sometimes you have a long function that does lots of transformations with side-effecting functions in between.  I want to be able to test this function from as high a level as possible, testing the composition is important.  My example was much simpler than a real situation as it was just an example.